# My apps not visible when using custom AdminSite

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd have a problem with custom AdminSite - my apps are not visible at the admin index and not accessible if i type appropriate URL to view their models. My problem is very similar to this: http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/881feb7eef80853a but it's kind of reverse problem - the bundled models are visible, but my custom are not.

My project named magic and it have app. named nullt

magic/admin.py:

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin, GroupAdmin 

class MagicAdmin(AdminSite):
    pass

admin_site = MagicAdmin()

admin_site.register(Group, GroupAdmin)
admin_site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

magic/nullt/admin.py

```
from magic.admin import admin_site
...
admin_site.register(Host, HostAdmin)
admin_site.register(Client, ClientAdmin)
...
```

magic/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import * #@UnusedWildImport
from magic.admin import admin_site

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin_site.urls)),
)
```

P.S. I'm using Django 1.2.2 installed with easy_install and Python 2.6.5 from Ubuntu 10.04 x86_64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the following two lines are commented in a new project's urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
```

From `django/contrib/admin/__init__.py`:

```
def autodiscover():
    """
    Auto-discover INSTALLED_APPS admin.py modules and fail silently when
    not present. This forces an import on them to register any admin bits they
    may want.
    """
```

This call may be necessary, even if you have a custom admin.

Comment: I read in the Django 1.2 documentation ((http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/) that there is really no need to use autodiscover when using your own AdminSite instance since you will likely be importing all the per-app admin.py modules in your myproject.admin module.

But actually the autodiscover() did the trick and I see my custom models in my custom admin :)
Thank you.